# How to import an already existing AWS Glue Job in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I deployed my Glue Jobs via Console and / or boto3 library until now.

I want to move to Infrastructure as Code using Terraform and manage all the Glue resources with this tool. Now to import already existing resources I'm aware of the command `terraform import ADDR ID` but I'm not sure how does that work.

Anyone can explain me how the import works with AWS Glue?

Answer (score 2):

Referencing https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/usage.html before importing an AWS Glue Job it is necessary to create a `.tf` file in the current working directory in your CLI.

So let's create a `main.tf` file like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "my-region-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/MyRole"
  }
}

resource "aws_glue_job" "my_job_resource" {
    name     = "my-glue-job"
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/MyGlueJobRole"
    command {
        name            = "glueetl"
        script_location = "s3://my-bucket/my-script.py"
        python_version  = "3"
    }
}
```

Where:

- `my-region-1` is the AWS region where operating
- `arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/MyRole` is the AWS Role assumed when running Terraform commands (which is what will access / interact with AWS Resources)
- `my-glue-job` is the name of the existing Glue Job
- `arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/MyGlueJobRole` is the AWS Role of the existing Glue Job
- `s3://my-bucket/my-script.py` is the S3 location of the Glue Job script

The `command` field is specific of the Glue Job import as considered a mandatory field, for other fields references and / or variations: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_job

Once the `main.tf` file is ready, run from the CLI in the same folder containing the file the following commands:

```
terraform init
terraform import aws_glue_job.my_job_resource my-glue-job
terraform show
```

Few details on these commands:

1. it will provision the folder with the necessary Terraform plug-ins necessary to interact with AWS
2. `my_job_resource` is the name of the block that identifies AWS resource while `my-glue-job` is the actual Glue Job name (in both cases refer to the `main.tf` file)
3. it will prompt the entire structure imported by the Glue Job.

Copy and replace the output generated from the last step into the `main.tf` file, replacing the block `resource "aws_glue_job" "my_job_resource"`.

It is now imported in a Terraform script.

The same principle can be reused for any other Glue resources, just reference the documentation page https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs